# subquery to get items with minimum rate

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have lets say 100 items that can be brought from 100 stores,i need a query that will give list of items found with minimum rate when search with store's name,suppose i select store name X then it should return list of items where rate is cheapest in the market.

Comment: I really want to help you , but you didn't wrote enough information: what are the tables that you have? what are the final result you wish? add some screens to explain your request.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'rate'? If it is price, here is my answer.

I'm supposing you have the following tables:

Store
(Id INT,
Title VARCHAR(100))

Item
(Id INT,
Title VARCHAR(100),
StoreId INT,
Price NUMERIC(19,2))

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT i.Title, i.Price
FROM dbo.Item i
INNER JOIN dbo.Store s ON s.Id = i.StoreId
WHERE s.Title = 'Store name'
ORDER BY i.Price
```